# How do I go direct to PayPal from the Cart Payment section Continue button instead of making the customer click the PayPal icon?

Tags: checkout, paypal-express, paypal-payments-pro, paypal-pro

[image]

I have disabled other options for a payment and just left PayPal.

Users must click on the small PayPal logo to be redirected to PayPal's payment page, if they don't understand that they get frustrated because nothing happens when they click the **Continue** button.

How can I make Magento automatically redirect the users to the PayPal payment page when they click the **Continue** button, instead of clicking the PayPal logo?

What is the best/easy option for this or workaround? Otherwise I would just hardcode the continue button, but there is probably some data generated by PayPal attached to the logo and I do not exactly know how to attach it to the button.

Still looking for a solution

@Edit

Just for a reference: This problem was not what I thought. The users were re-directed to the PayPal when they clicked Continue button. It just took more seconds than I thought...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't the default behaviour with PayPal Standard. It should allow you to hit continue, be redirected to PayPal to complete, then return to the store for the success page.

Are you by chance using PayPal Express - because that would alter the checkout flow completely. It should occur during the cart phase (not during checkout), where it redirects to PayPal to collect all information (address etc.) - then returns to Magento for final confirmation.

Comment: Yes I am using paypal express, do you suggest I should use paypal standard

Comment: I think it's ok to use paypal express during the checkout (removing the paypal express buttons from the catalog product pages). Am I right? Even though it was designed to work differently. Or do I break some paypal guidelines and rules? Do you know anything about it?

Comment: Currently during the checkout process, users are redirected to the paypal page, where they enter payment details. They just have to click at the small logo instead of the continue button, when there is a second payment option, all they have to do it select the desired processor (from the list where there is radio button)e.g. paypal or authorise and the continue button works

Comment: That's your call really. Depends on what customer experience you want. The purpose of PayPal Express is to go direct to PayPal from the cart (bypassing the entire Magento checkout) and use the customer's stored address in PayPal to populate shipping/billing info. It doesn't really make sense to have the customer go through the checkout steps, to then select PayPal Express, to then have their address filled in by PayPal anyway. If you want a customer to register/complete checkout on your site, stick with Standard.

Comment: if you ONLY using Paypal express why don't you disable the onepage checkout?

Comment: @Ahmed El Awadi It's something to think about. In my current configuration, users go through standard checkout, but then pay with paypal express. I know that paypal-express was designed to allow users pay from the catalog product page.